# What are practical uses of the $destroy event of jqLite (or AngularJS-patched jQuery)?

Tags: angularjs

First all, I want to be clear that my question is *NOT* about the $destroy event associated with AngularJS Scope.

AngularJS patches jQuery to make all jQuery's DOM destruction apis to fire a `$destroy` event on all DOM nodes being removed. jqLite (comes with AngularJS) also behaves in the same way, if no jQuery is used. I have seen the `$destroy` event been used (ie. bind to) in a few occurrences in AngularJS' source. But still, I cannot reason what are some practical uses of binding to the `$destroy` event on DOM elements being removed. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You could bind to `$destroy` to also destroy the scope associated with element.

Comment: More than a year later, I still can't find any good examples for this, or even clarity about differences between when angular's $destroy and jQuery $destroy are firing...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a valid issue from the AngularJS github repository that could be solved with this event: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3237

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Amh8W/2/

```
$element.on('$destroy', function() {
                $scope.window.close();
              });
```

Window is closed when directive is removed - try to handle that in another way. $destroy has functionalty similar to destructor.