# Angularjs javascript loading sometime not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

The following AngularJS controller get id parameter from html page ,then the controller should load file1.js or file2.js depending on this id ,the files loaded but It sometimes work and sometime not work.

```
 myappApp.controller('ChartConfigController', function ($scope, ChartConfigService) {
 $scope.findOne= function() {
 ChartConfigService.findOne($scope.id).then(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj.type);
        var x = obj.type;
        if (x=="pie") {
            $.getScript("file1.js", function(){
                   console.log("File 1 loaded");
                });
        } else if (x=="line") {
            $.getScript("file2.js", function(){
                   console.log("File 2 loaded");
                });
        } else {
            console.log("not found");
        }

    });
 };      
});
```

html page

```
 <div id="form">
 <form action="" method="get">
 <input ng-model="id"  required>
 <input type="submit" ng-click="findOne()">
 </form>
 </div>

  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 
   400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto">   </div>
```

file1.js and file2.js contain highchart code like this,It loaded but didn't execute,I don't know why.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
    plotShadow: false
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
        ['Firefox',   45.0],
        ['IE',       26.8],
        {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        },
        ['Safari',    8.5],
        ['Opera',     6.2],
        ['Others',   0.7]
    ]
  }]
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that $scope.id might not be reflecting in the controller. If there is new scope being created by any parent of the  element, scope variable "id" will be created under this scope and hence will not update in the controller scope.

The best practice is to wrap all input ng-model inside a scope object initiated at the controller, like so....

```
myappApp.controller('ChartConfigController', function ($scope, ChartConfigService) {
 $scope.chart_obj = {};
 $scope.findOne= function() {
   ChartConfigService.findOne($scope.chart_obj.id).then(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.type);
    var x = obj.type;
    if (x=="pie") {
        $.getScript("file1.js", function(){
               console.log("File 1 loaded");
            });
    } else if (x=="line") {
        $.getScript("file2.js", function(){
               console.log("File 2 loaded");
            });
    } else {
        console.log("not found");
    }

   });
 };      
});
```

And in html as

```
<input ng-model="chart_obj.id"  required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating 2 directives and doing an `ng-if` to select which directive to show? I don't think the code gets executed. Have you verified that?

Edit: Or you can create one directive and pass the atribute to that directive.

Angular uses a special `$compile` function to modify the DOM. That's why your changes might have not been reflected. If you do DOM manipulation outside of Angular I strongly suggest wrapping it inside a directive. And don't forget to delete your objects after the directive gets destroyed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744623/what-are-practical-uses-of-the-destroy-event-of-jqlite-or-angularjs-patched-jq)